# EF "generate database from model" does not work for views

Tags: entity-framework

I use EF Model First, sometimes import new views, and after making changes, do a "generate database from model" in order to build a new clean database that I can compare to my production database, in order to generate a compare script, so that I can update the production database as part of the deploy.

However, if I "update model from database" for a new view, I get a defining query like below that has the actual view definition. So far so good.

```
          <EntitySet Name="vChainSubscriptions" EntityType="Self.vChainSubscriptions" store:Type="Views" store:Schema="dbo">
        <DefiningQuery>SELECT 
[vChainSubscriptions].[ChainName] AS [ChainName], 
[vChainSubscriptions].[ChainActive] AS [ChainActive], 
[vChainSubscriptions].[Changed] AS [Changed], 
[vChainSubscriptions].[ChangedBy] AS [ChangedBy]
FROM [dbo].[vChainSubscriptions] AS [vChainSubscriptions]</DefiningQuery>
      </EntitySet>
```

Then perhaps after some other model changes, I want to "generate database from model" to create a new temp database that I can compare to the old database, and my view is turned into a table because the edmx file was updated as part of the database generation process!

```
    <EntitySet Name="vChainSubscriptions" EntityType="TxData.Store.vChainSubscriptions" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
```

How can I prevent this terrible behavior? Generate model from database and model back to database should round trip and NOT change my view into a table, but rather should create the new view as a view using "Create View" not "Create Table".

Comment: EF has never properly supported views... My advice, give up on it.. it will just waste many hours of your time and leave you very frustrated.

Comment: Indeed. We plan to switch to Code First since MSFT has all but abandoned Database First and Model First even though Code First was so poor when EF started none of us wanted to use it. Model First and Database First should round trip and also be compatible with Code First. You should be able to update using any of the 3 approaches and have the changes reflected in the other two. All 3 approaches have their strengths and weaknesses and should truly be interchangeable at the design level.

Comment: I don't mean give up on EF, I mean give up on using Views with EF.  Either use stored procs, or recreate your views in compiled expressions.

Comment: No intention of giving up. Just plan to switch to Code First where I can use view with a minor tweak to not have the migrations try to create a table in the target database which I like to create for comparison to the production database to check what all changed after any model or association changes.